# WPF ListBox WrapPanel: MouseOver and SelectedItem transparant

Tags: wpf, listbox

I have the following Listbox:

```
            <ListBox Grid.Row="1" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}">
            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True">
                    </WrapPanel>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        </ListBox>
```

But when I do a mouseover or select an item, the item is "blue". 
I want it to be transparant.

Also I want the item to be underlined if selected.

MyItem is an observableCollection of myItem:

```
public class MyItem
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public bool Selected{ get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can for example simply setup the default style for the ListBoxItem at the top of your xaml file or ideally inside of your resources xaml file. You must override default control template in order to achive that. You don't have to setup triggers directly. Here's example. Have fun.

```
<Window x:Class="StackPoC.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:StackPoC"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                    <Border x:Name="border"
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}">
                        <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}"
                                          HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}" />
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}">
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

**EDIT**

I haven't read the part about underline on Selected*. Well.. You already know that you had to create custom control template in order to get rid of the selection. I wont write the code for you but I will give you an idea on how to do that ;)  Create Triggers inside of a node ControlTemplate.Triggers according to the IsSelected property and then use Setter in order to setup your desired appearance. Good luck.